# Apple M1 Pytorch : NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::_pin_memory' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend

Tags: pytorch, gpu, apple-m1

This python script

```py
import torch 
mps_device = torch.device("mps")
x = torch.ones(2, device=mps_device)
x.to("cpu").pin_memory()
```

raises this error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/path/to/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    x.to("cpu", non_blocking=True).pin_memory()
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::_pin_memory' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'aten::_pin_memory' is only available for these backends: [MPS, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradHIP, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradIPU, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradVE, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, AutogradPrivateUse1, AutogradPrivateUse2, AutogradPrivateUse3, AutogradNestedTensor, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].

MPS: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/build/aten/src/ATen/RegisterMPS.cpp:20632 [kernel]
BackendSelect: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/build/aten/src/ATen/RegisterBackendSelect.cpp:726 [kernel]
Python: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:140 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/functorch/DynamicLayer.cpp:488 [backend fallback]
Functionalize: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/FunctionalizeFallbackKernel.cpp:291 [backend fallback]
Named: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback]
Conjugate: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/ConjugateFallback.cpp:18 [backend fallback]
Negative: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/NegateFallback.cpp:18 [backend fallback]
ZeroTensor: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
ADInplaceOrView: fallthrough registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:64 [backend fallback]
AutogradOther: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradCPU: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradCUDA: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradHIP: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradXLA: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradMPS: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradIPU: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradXPU: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradHPU: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradVE: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradLazy: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradMeta: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradPrivateUse1: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradPrivateUse2: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradPrivateUse3: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
AutogradNestedTensor: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp:14904 [autograd kernel]
Tracer: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_0.cpp:16458 [kernel]
AutocastCPU: fallthrough registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/autocast_mode.cpp:482 [backend fallback]
AutocastCUDA: fallthrough registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/autocast_mode.cpp:324 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchBatched: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/functorch/LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:743 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/functorch/VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback]
Batched: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/BatchingRegistrations.cpp:1064 [backend fallback]
VmapMode: fallthrough registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/functorch/TensorWrapper.cpp:189 [backend fallback]
PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:148 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/functorch/DynamicLayer.cpp:484 [backend fallback]
PythonDispatcher: registered at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:144 [backend fallback]
```

It seems like the `MPS` backend should be available on my laptop, but I do not know how to check this. Can this error be resolved?

Setup:

- Chip: Apple M1 Pro
- Memory: 16G
- macOS: 13.0.1
- torch: 1.13.0
- torchvision: 0.14.0
- installation: `pip install torch torchvision -U`

Comment: Have you tried the block at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/mps.html ? i.e. what are the results of calling `torch.backends.mps.is_available()` and `torch.backends.mps.is_built()` ? I am on 12.2.1 so I get `False`, `True` for those.

Comment: Are you by any chance running inside a container?

Comment: I get `True` for both `is_available` and `is_build` (also not in a container)